# Adding dictionary items, while loop

Tags: python

I am unsure what to equal `spent` to. I am trying to add the `[2]` dictionary item for each key.

```
movies = {
1:('The Shawshank Redemption' , 'Bob', 25, 5),
2:('The Godfather', 'Kelly', 25, 4),
3:('The Dark Knight', 'Tyler', 25, 3),
4:('12 Angry Men', 'Bob', 25, 4),
5:('The Shawshank Redemption' , 'Bill', 35, 4),
6:('The Godfather', 'Sally', 35, 5),
7:('The Dark Knight', 'Suzy', 19, 5),
8:('12 Angry Men', 'Frank', 19, 3),
9:('The Shawshank Redemption' , 'Sally', 35, 5),
10:('The Godfather', 'Leslie', 40, 2),
11:('The Green Knight', 'Tom', 35, 2),
12:('14 Angry Men', 'Kaitlyn', 25, 4)}

spent = 
x = 1
while spent < max(movies.keys()):
   spent += movies[x][2]
    x += 1
else:
   print ('The total money spent is:', spent)
```

Comment: 1) This code has syntax errors. 2) It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: I honestly can't tell what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: What should `movies` be?

Comment: Don't add code in comments. Please edit your question instead.

Comment: Why are you using a dict with ascending integer keys to store that data when you could just store it in a list instead?

Comment: @Bazingaa That's what I am having trouble determining. I originally set it to `0`

Comment: A list doesn't have a `keys()` method

Comment: @Aran-Fey, No reason, I changed it to a list instead.

Comment: Don't change your question after you've received answers. I'm rolling back that edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't compare `spent` to anything, it just contains the total. Use a `for` loop to loop over the dictionary elements.

There's no need to increment `x` in the loop, it's just the number of elements in the dictionary, which you can get with `len()`.

```
spent = 0
x = len(movies)
for movie in movies.values():
    spent += movie[2]
print('The total money spent is:', spent)
```

You can also use the built-in `sum()` function with a list comprehension.

```
spent = sum(movie[2] for movie in movies)
```

The equivalent `while` loop needs to compare `x` with the number of dictionary elements:

```
x = 1
spent = 0
while x <= len(movies):
    spent += movies[x][2]
    x += 1
```

This assumes that the dictionary keys are sequential numbers starting from `1`. Normally you would use a list for something like this, dictionaries are used when you have less ordered keys. If it were a list, you have to adjust to account for list indexes starting at `0` rather than `1`:

```
x = 0
spent = 0
while x < len(movies):
    spent += movies[x][2]
    x += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to practice with while-loops though.

Comment: @rockymountain I've added how to do it with `while`.

Comment: You should put that in the question.

Comment: I created a list within a list. The list is called `movielist`, so when I do this with a list instead, I am getting the error: (IndexError: list index out of range) for line `spent += movielist[x][2]`

Comment: @rockymountain List indexes start at 0 and end at `len(movies)-1`. So you need to initialize `x = 0` and change `<=` to `<`.